# Store HTML in Database containing a PHP function?

Tags: php, html, sql

I am aiming to store an HTML textbox in my MySQL database , which contains a php function to reference  a value in another database, and then display this textbox on another page by accessing the database.

This is what I have so far:

***DBfunctions***

```
<?php
function createTextBox()
{
$otherData =getContent();
$textBox = "<input type='text' name='firstname' value = $otherData>";
return $textBox;
}

function getContent()
{
global $pdo;
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT data FROM content WHERE id =1');
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchColumn();
return $result;
 }

$value= createTextBox(); 

function readContent()
{
global $pdo;
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT data FROM database WHERE id =1');
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Pages');
return $result;
}

global $pdo;
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE database set content = '$value' WHERE id 
=1");
$statement->execute();
?>
```

***home***

```
 <?php 

 require_once 'DBfunctions.php';

 $content = readContent();

 ?>

<html>

<?php foreach ($results as $data): ?>
<?= $data ->content?>
<?php endforeach ?>

</html>
```

The problem seems to be that when I assign the value of $textbox in the createTextBox function , it does not use the value of $otherData and instead just views it as a string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Why are you aiming to store HTML in MySQL to start with? Store the desired **content** in your database, and then insert the content into structured HTML dynamically.

Comment: Not sure what's happening with your update command, it should be more along the lines of: 'UPDATE table SET fieldname = value WHERE constraint', and as you are using a prepared statement, why not use a placeholder?

Comment: Your code is very confusing. By not naming things properly you're mixing them up. Start with giving your database tables correct names. Don't use 'database', 'data' and 'content', they are meaningless since everything is a database, has data, and has content. This is especially bad because you also seem to have a table and column, both named 'content'. You have the same problem with your function names: 'getContent' and 'readContent' retrieve data from two different db tables, who would have guessed? Also check the arguments of 'fetchAll()', they seem to be wrong.

Comment: @obsidianAge Im making a content management system and would like to allow the user the ability to add new webpages - to do this Im storing them as HTML in a database.

Comment: @progrock the update command seems to work , I am new to php though and just followed a tutorial for this.

Comment: @i used these database names just as practice before I try to implement it into the real system- but yeah theyre pretty confusing

Comment: @ill restructure this question because i think theres a lot of irrelevant info here...

Comment: This is definitely an an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) - something you are approaching the wrong way. Step back for a moment and work out *specifically* what you want to differ between users. For example, if you want them to be able to have different page background colours, you'd set their chosen colour in the database, and output it as `<div class="<?php echo $colour; ?>">`. For 'themes', offer them a **choice**, and use an `if` conditional to output HTML. You should never store full HTML in a database - there's a separation of markup and logic for a reason :)

Comment: @obsidianAge
I would love your insight for my particular problem: The user needs to be be able to create a webpage, every webpage will have a default structure (navbar etc).


The pages content must also be updatable by the user. 


I have a VERY ...glitchy way of solving this problem which is :


upload blank webpages to the server ,when the user wants to create a new page , it will insert the "page structure" from the database to a blank page , and then with the embedded PHP from the structure, create a new tab on the website. 


I cant find a good way for a user to add a page.